# Best way to run "self monitoring" - asyncio/thread?

Tags: multithreading, celery, python-asyncio

Python 3.10.6

ManagerTask() - responsible of executing Task() methods .
Note , Task's method are actually are Celery tasks (async ).

I'd like to add the option to track those tasks execution inside ManagerTask class.
I manage to get it work but as it my first asyncio I'm not sure i'm doing it right ,
(I'm aware of Flower).

Second, at current running single Main() which orchestrating executing Task() ,
In real world need to expand it to support executing multiple sessions of Main() in parallel.

```
        
class ManagerTask:

    def __init__(self ,id:int ) -> None:
        self.id = id
        self.tasks: List["Task"] = []
        self.executed_tasks: List["Task"] = []
        self.state = State.SCHEDULED


    def load_tasks(self , configs: List[Dict]):
        # code for loading tasks


    async def run(self):
        """ Execute all tasks and start monitor results"""

        execute_task = asyncio.create_task(self.task_exec())
        monitor_progresss = asyncio.create_task(self.monitor_progress())
        await execute_task
        await monitor_progresss
        
    async def monitor_progress(self):
        """ If one task Failed - Main.state failed if all success mark Main.state -success"""
        import time
        failure_flag = False
        count_success = 0
        i = 0

        while True:     
            state = self.executed_tasks[i].task_run.state 

            if state == 'SUCCESS':
                count_success += 1      
                i += 1

            if state == 'FAILURE':
                failure_flag = True
                i += 1

            print(f'Rule_ID:{self.executed_tasks[i].rule_id} \
                 \nCelery_UUID:{self.executed_tasks[i].task_celery_id} \
                 \nstatus - {self.executed_tasks[i].task_run.state}')
                 
            #  all tasks proccessed (either failed/success)  

            if i == len(self.executed_tasks) -1:
                if failure_flag:
                    self.state = State.FAILED
                elif count_success == len(self.executed_tasks) :
                    self.state = State.FINISHED
                break;

            # otherwise wait 
            await asyncio.sleep(3)                        
                
         
    async def task_exec(self):
        for task in self.starting_tasks:
            task.run()
```

client (execute the app):

```
...code

cust = MainTask(id=1)    
cust.load_tasks(configs=rules ,db_connections=db_connections)
asyncio.run(cust.run())

print("MainTask State:" + cust.state)
```

Example of output:

```
Rule_ID:4
Celery_UUID:fecde27c-b58a-43cd-9498-3478404c248b                    
status - FAILURE
....
Rule_ID:6
Celery_UUID:85df9bba-3d75-4b00-a533-a81cd3f6afb3                    
status - SUCCESS

MainTask State:Failed
```

1.Is that is proper way executing asyncio ?
2.for running multiple MainTask , how I should do it? Thread/Asyncio?
As this program executing all task using celery I think i should also run in asyncio but not sure .
second , would be thankful for guidance if this is the right approach

```
async def exec_id(id):
    cust = MainTask(id=id)    
    cust.load_tasks(configs=rules ,...)
    await cust.run()

async def main():
    ids = [111,222,333]

    for id in ids:
        await exec_id(id)


        
asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: I don't understand your `task_exec` method - what are you trying to do there, and what kind of objects are in `self.starting_tasks`?  They don't appear to be asyncio.Task objects, since those are created by `asyncio.create_task` or `asyncio.loop.create_task`.  Here you are calling their `run` method, which an instantiated Task object won't have.

Comment: This question is hard to understand because of the poor English grammar. But more importantly it does not contain a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To make it easier for people to help you _and_ to make this question valuable to other people, please put in some effort to make your code **minimal**, complete and reproducible.